# Gmail Java Mail SMTP: Removing internal host names and IP addresses from mail message headers

Tags: java, smtp

While I trying to send email from java mail message header is exposing information about hostname and internal IP address(using GMAIL), How I can remove the IP 49.37.45.79?

```
Received: from 52669349336 ([49.37.45.79])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id h16-20020a17090a051000b001efa9e83927sm4225730pjh.51.2022.09.18.00.36.18
        for <test.sahu1@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 18 Sep 2022 00:36:35 -0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That an email that you sent will not have that header when reaching the recipient? Or that an email that you received will be stripped off these headers before you process it further?

Comment: As I shared I don't want to expose my Ip to the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in the comment to the question, you intend to hide the IP address of your email client (MUA) and that of the MSA.

Short answer: forget it!

Longer answer: The header shown as a sample in your question will be added to the email by the various MTAs. That with the IP address of your MUA is added by the MSA (the Mail Subscription Agent – that SMTP 'server' that your email client connects to to send the email), that of the MSA is added by the next MTA in the communication chain, and so on, until finally the mail box server will add the header for the MDA, the mail delivery agent that is the last one before the email reaches the recipient's inbox.

There is nothing you can do about that on the sender side, no matter how you want to tweak the JavaMail library – the whole thing happens elsewhere.

Of course you can write your own MSA that does not add the IP address of the MUAs that connect to it. But at least the IP address of that MSA will be published by the next MTA in sequence, or your emails will end in limbo (or /dev/nul). And as you have to run that MSA on your environment, it does not really matter whether it publishes the IP address of your MUA – tracking down the MSA will already reveal you.

---

There may be some public MSAs that offer it as a service that they do not reveal the IP address of the MUA, but Google Mail is definitely not one of these.

As far as I remember, the various bulk email providers do not reveal the IP address of the original sender, but that's because they generate the emails internally and use their own IP address for the email's origin. But in this case, the real sender is given with the FROM header, at least.